# Connecting to WebDAV https with login and password?

Tags: webdav

Running 14.04 unity

Hi, I can get Nautilus to recognize and 'connect' to a remote WebDAV server (meaning the server shows up) but I am never prompted to enter my username and password, thus I cannot see any of the files.  Any ideas?